# Situar dos div uno al lado del otro

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Como puedo situar estos dos div uno al lado del otro. El de la izquierda ocupando un 15% y el de la derecha un 84%

```css
.container {
    width: 99.5%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid" id="main-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">col-2</div>
                <div class="col-10">col-10</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrias utilizar las clases "row" y col-sm-x" para indicar que es una fila y el tamaño de cada columna de esa fila. revisa el layout de bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#all-breakpoints)

Comment: Genial la idea aunque ahora tengo un pequeño problema. La idea es que me ocupe todo el ancho del monitor y no lo hace. Tengo puesto que el container ocupe el 99.5% del ancho de la pagina pero no me lo hace. Actualizo la pregunta

Comment: Si quieres que ocupe el 100% de la pantalla debes dejar que sea `container-fluid` solo, es decir, quitar tu `div` con la clase `container` ya que en bootstrap esa no ocupa toda la pantalla. Para evitar problemas también te recomiendo que indiques si quieres que ocupe 2 columnas en lg, md o sm, a ponerlo tal cual a mí me da problemas siempre.

Comment: Genial ;D Me soluciono el problema. Ponlo como respuesta si ves oportuno. Muchas gracias !!

Answer (score 4):

Puedes también hacerlo sin Bootstrap, aplicando tú el display: flex al contenedor de los dos div, que en este caso es la clase row y le aplicamos un 100% del ancho.

```
   .row {
     display: flex;
     width: 100%;
  }
```

Además le añadimos clases a ambos div en el HTML y le decimos el porcentaje que quieres para cada uno.

```
    .col1 {
       background: grey;
       width: 15%;
}
    .col2 {
       border: white;
       background: grey;
       width: 85%;
}
```

Aquí te dejo el código completo modificado. Si lo ejecutas dentro del container los divs se comportan como tú quieres.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

```css
.col1 {
   background: grey;
   width: 15%;
}
.col2 {
   border: white;
   background: grey;
   width: 85%;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid" id="main-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col1">col-2</div>
                <div class="col2">col-10</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 2):

Botstrap tiene 2 tipos de contenedores:

1. `container` :  que ocupa el 90% del total de la pantalla.
2. `container-fluid` : que ocupa el 100% de la pantalla

En bootstrap, todo lo que vaya dentro del contenedor es aconsejable usar `row`.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row text-white text-center">
    <div class="col-2 bg-dark border">DIV 1</div>
    <div class="col-10 bg-dark border">DIV 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```